# Is Python's xlrd 0.9.2 backward compatible with 0.7?

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

We're using John Machin's [xlrd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) 0.7.1 in about 20 projects to read Excel spreadsheets.  Would updating to the latest version (0.9.2) work out of the box or are there known incompatibilities we should plan for?

Comment: don't you have (unit)tests that should tell you?

Comment: @mata: Our team, no, as we're starting a new project that needs some of the new functionality.  The 20+ other teams probably have unit tests.  But before we start lobbying them to update our shared environment, we'd like to have a general feel for the effort involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Chris Withers, one of the maintainers of `xlrd` (in a message he sent today (2013-04-29) to the `python-excel` mailing list):

> [The] only API change between 0.6 and 0.9 is the removal of the
>   'pickleable' parameter to open_workbook. However, this was removed
>   because it hadn't worked in a long long time. ... Applications written
>   for 0.6.x will still work without change when using 0.9.2.

I would expect whatever you have now to work as-is with the latest `xlrd`.